# How to match exception with double character with Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string

Got this string and regex findall:

```
txt = """
  dx d_2,222.22     ,,
  dy h..{3,333.33}  ,,
dz b#(1,111.11) ,,   dx-ay relative 4,444.44 ,, 
"""
for n in re.findall( r'([-\w]+){1}\W+([^,{2}]+)\s+,,\W+', txt ) :
    axis, value = n
    print "a:", axis 
    print "v:", value
```

In second (value) group I am trying to match anything except double commas, but it seems to catch only one `","`. I can got it in this example with simple `(.*?)` but for certain reasons it got to be everything except `",,"`. Thank you.

EDIT: To see what I want to accomplish just use `r'([-\w]+){1}\W+(.*?)\s+,,\W+'` instead. It will give you such output:

```
a: dx
v: d_2,222.22
a: dy
v: h..{3,333.33}
a: dz
v: b#(1,111.11)
a: dx-ay
v: relative 4,444.44
```

EDIT #2: Please, answer which did not include double comma exception is not what is needed. Is there a solution...should be. So patern is :

Any whitespace - word with possibly `"-"` - than `" "` - and everything to `",,"` except itself.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?

Comment: What's your expected output? And Why you used this `[^,{2}]` ?

Comment: I wrote an edit to explain. Thank you.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556312/rails-3-precompiling-all-css-sass-and-scss-files-in-a-folder

Comment: so if `(.*?)` works, why can't it be `(.*?)`?

Comment: `@Georg` story would be too long...but picture that I only want to figure out how to do it in other way.

Comment: @Alex still i can't figure out what's your actual question is.. :;)

Comment: No, `,,` is obligatory. It's kinda separator for every (axis,value) repetition, or (key,value) if you prefer; and key is separated from value with 1st `" "`.

Answer (score 3):

`[^,{2}]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches  any character except: `',', '{', '2', '}'`

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match `only one out of several characters`.

It should be `([^,]{2})+`

```
(                        group and capture to \1
  [^,]{2}                  any character except: ',' (2 times)
)+                       end of \1
```

---

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2

```
 ([-\w]+)\s+(.*?)\s+,,
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS1wA0/1)

[image]

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([-\w]+)\s+(.*?)\s+,,')
test_str = u"..."

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

**Note:** use `\s*` instead of `\s+` if spaces are optional.

Comment: share compete information for clear picture. What is expected output?

Comment: @Alex, instead of `@User` it would be better to write "@user3218114".

Answer (score 1):

`r'(?<=,,)\s+([-\w]+)\s(.*?)(?:,,)'` is expression what is needed here. Much more simpler than I could thought.

`r'(?<=,,)` is positive lookbehind assertion and it will find a match in string which is after double commas , since the lookbehind will back up 2 chars and check if the contained pattern matches.

`(?:,,)` as last one is non-capturing version of regular parentheses, so everything in between should match.

`\s` or `\s+` is there only for the matter of this specific type of string.