# javascript regex for <script tag, ignore type but add source if it exists

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code working using two regex's the first grabs anything inbetween the `<script></script>` tags regardless if they have a `type="text/javascript"` specified.  The second grabs the source from the remaining tags if any and creates an array of urls to write.  Is there a way to do this with a single regex?

Apparently my type ignore isn't working either.

Because no one seems to read or understand the question here is the string I am given.  This must be converted to html and the external js appended and the inline js added to the page.  I have this working fine, just wanted to make these few enhancements.  I realize parsing html is not good practice, I have said this but this is the assignment I was given.

```
var d = '<script>alert("inline javascript 1");</\script><h1>html only</h1><h2>subtitle.</h2><script>alert("inline javascript 2");</\script><script>alert("inline javascript 3");</\script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></\script><script>alert("more inline javascript");</\script><p>More Content.</p>';

var regInline = /<script[^type>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gmi;
var regSrc = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"><\/script>/gmi;
// Extract inline javascript.
content = content.replace(regInline, function() {
    inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
});
// Extract external javascript urls.
content = content.replace(regSrc, function() {
    urls.push(arguments[1]); 
});
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842)

Comment: Ok great, I have a string that contains html, <script>inline js</script> and <script src="to an external file"></script>, how else should I iterate through the string and add this to the page?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[indexhere].innerHTML`

Comment: All of them: `var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); var example = []; for(i in x) { example.push(x[i].innerHTML); } console.log(example);`

Comment: there is no script element in the dom at this point, so getElementsByTagName will not work.  Again I have a string with script/html/etc and I need a regex to parse it into html.

Comment: You don't need to parse the string with RegExp. Just create a temporary element to the `document`, add the string as `innerHTML`, make changes and parse to a string again if needed. What comes to the functions within arguments of the `replace` methods, they have to return some value. Without returning a value they return `undefined`, which probably is unwanted result.

Comment: It has to be appended to a target container or I would just create/append a new element.  I added return = ''; in the regex and it seemed to remove the undefindes.  Thanks though

Comment: No, it must not append to any element. Just create it only. This way it will be parseable. When you assign new elements to a local variable in a function, elements are gone after function has been executed. In a case the newly created elements can be used as they are, you can append them to a target element _after_ manipulating the content.

Comment: Please check [an example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1njagv3k/).

Answer (score 0):

**`[^type]` does *not* negate sequences that are not `"type"`,** it instead negates any characters from the list `"t"`, `"y"`, `"p"` or `"e"`.

This means you should not use `[^type>]`. Instead, try this regex:

```
var regInline = /<script(?:(?!type).)*>(.*?)<\/script>/sgmi;
```

Note that `[\s\S]` is replaced to `.` with `/s`ingleline modifier.

**Read more:**

- [Rails 3 - Precompiling all css, sass and scss files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24681155/3622940)